# Поля содержащее одно из двух наперед заданных значений в MySQL таблицах

Tags: mysql

Мне нужно создать в таблице поле, которое бы содержало данные о том подтвердил ли пользователь е-мейл. Т.е. возможно всего лишь два варианта вводимых данных - да и нет.

Не знаю как лучше сделать в таком случае. Просто сделать поле и писать в него 0 или 1, или есть какие-то виды полей, специально предназначенные для этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ENUM('значение1','значение2',...)`

Перечисление. Перечисляемый тип данных. Объект строки может иметь только одно значение, выбранное из заданного списка величин `'значение1', 'значение2', ..., NULL`.

По занимаемой памяти - один байт используется для перечисления до 255 возможных величин. То есть в вашем конретном случае 1 бит.

Answer (score 1):

Использую флаги `0/1` с типом данных `tinyint`.

Answer (score 0):

Для заранее известных значений лучше всего подходит `ENUM` (перечисление).